# Uploading Images from UIImage Picker onto new Firebase (Swift)

Tags: ios, firebase, swift2, uiimagepickercontroller, firebase-storage

I have a UIImagePicker set up within my app that works fine. I would like to upload a profile picture to Firebase when my UIImage picker has been chosen. Here is my function for when a picture has been selected.

```
    //image picker did finish code
func imagePickerController(picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : AnyObject]) {

    let chosenImage = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage] as! UIImage
    profilePic.contentMode = .ScaleAspectFill
    profilePic.image = chosenImage
    profilePic.hidden = false
    buttonStack.hidden = true
    changeButtonView.hidden = false
    self.statusLabel.text = "Here is Your Profile Picture"

    dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)


}
```

The new documentation states that we need to declare a NSURl in order to upload a file. Here is my attempt to find the NSURL of the given file, but it doesn't work. Here is the documentation and a link to it:https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/ios/upload-files#upload_from_data_in_memory

```
// File located on disk
let localFile: NSURL = ...
// Create a reference to the file you want to upload
let riversRef = storageRef.child("images/rivers.jpg")

// Upload the file to the path "images/rivers.jpg"
let uploadTask = riversRef.putFile(localFile, metadata: nil) { metadata, error in
  if (error != nil) {
    // Uh-oh, an error occurred!
  } else {
    // Metadata contains file metadata such as size, content-type, and download URL.
    let downloadURL = metadata!.downloadURL
  }
}
```

Here is my attempt for retrieving the NSURL of the UIImagePicker:

```
//image picker did finish code
    func imagePickerController(picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : AnyObject]) {

        let chosenImage = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage] as! UIImage
        //getting the object's url
        let imageUrl = info[UIImagePickerControllerReferenceURL] as! NSURL
        let imageName = imageUrl.lastPathComponent
        let documentDir = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.DocumentDirectory, .UserDomainMask, true).first! as String;
        let photoUrl = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: documentDir)
        let localPath = photoUrl.URLByAppendingPathComponent(imageName!)
        self.localFile = localPath

        profilePic.contentMode = .ScaleAspectFill
        profilePic.image = chosenImage
        profilePic.hidden = false
        buttonStack.hidden = true
        changeButtonView.hidden = false
        self.statusLabel.text = "Here is Your Profile Picture"

        dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)


    }
```

I believe that I am also running into difficulties if the image was taken from the camera instead of the gallery since it is not saved on the device yet. How do I find this image/snapshots's NSURL?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Here is my method to upload and download the user profile  photo from firebase storage:

```
    func imagePickerController(picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingImage image: UIImage, editingInfo: [String : AnyObject]?) {
    userPhoto.image = image
    dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
    var data = NSData()
    data = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(userPhoto.image!, 0.8)!
    // set upload path
    let filePath = "\(FIRAuth.auth()!.currentUser!.uid)/\("userPhoto")"
    let metaData = FIRStorageMetadata()
    metaData.contentType = "image/jpg"
    self.storageRef.child(filePath).putData(data, metadata: metaData){(metaData,error) in
        if let error = error {
            print(error.localizedDescription)
            return
        }else{
        //store downloadURL
        let downloadURL = metaData!.downloadURL()!.absoluteString
        //store downloadURL at database
    self.databaseRef.child("users").child(FIRAuth.auth()!.currentUser!.uid).updateChildValues(["userPhoto": downloadURL])
        }

        }
                   }
```

I also store the Image URL into firebase database and check if the user has a profile photo or you might get a crash:

```
 //get photo back
        
     databaseRef.child("users").child(userID!).observeSingleEventOfType(.Value, withBlock: { (snapshot) in
            // check if user has photo
            if snapshot.hasChild("userPhoto"){
                // set image locatin
                let filePath = "\(userID!)/\("userPhoto")"
                // Assuming a < 10MB file, though you can change that
                self.storageRef.child(filePath).dataWithMaxSize(10*1024*1024, completion: { (data, error) in
                    
                    let userPhoto = UIImage(data: data!)
                    self.userPhoto.image = userPhoto
                })
            }
        })
```

Comment: you can also create the path like this : let path = "\(NSUUID().uuidString)"

Comment: @Neen great suggestion! Thanks.

Comment: The upload bit works great. The download does not work for me. I had to do it differently.

Answer (score 4):

## Simple 2020 example

1. Don't forget to add `pod 'Firebase/Storage'` to your podfile, and `pod install`
2. Add **two** delegates to your class

   ```
   class YourScreen: UIViewController, 
     UIImagePickerControllerDelegate, UINavigationControllerDelegate {
   ```
3. Storyboard, button, link to ...

   ```
   @IBAction func tapCameraButton() {
   let picker = UIImagePickerController()
   picker.allowsEditing = true
   picker.delegate = self
   present(picker, animated: true)
   }
   ```

   and then

   ```
   func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController,
   didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [UIImagePickerController.InfoKey : Any]) {

    guard let im: UIImage = info[.editedImage] as? UIImage else { return }
    guard let d: Data = im.jpegData(compressionQuality: 0.5) else { return }

    let md = StorageMetadata()
    md.contentType = "image/png"

    let ref = Storage.storage().reference().child("someFolder/12345678.jpg")

    ref.putData(d, metadata: md) { (metadata, error) in
        if error == nil {
            ref.downloadURL(completion: { (url, error) in
                print("Done, url is \(String(describing: url))")
            })
        }else{
            print("error \(String(describing: error))")
        }
    }

    dismiss(animated: true)
   }
   ```

## But where do you put the image?

At the code,

```
... .child("someFolder/12345678.jpg")
```

Almost inevitably,

• as the folder name use the user's id, the chat id, the feed id or a similar concept

• for the name, the only possibility is a uuid

Hence almost always

```
let f = chatId + "/" + UUID().uuidString + ".jpg"
let ref = Storage.storage().reference().child(f)
```

Comment: Very well done. This is the procedure I used. Thanks for sharing.

Comment: really my pleasure.  it is so #@$@#ing annoying working this sort of stuff out :/  and the syntax changes every few yrs.

Answer (score 1):

Working in Swift 4.2

Here i am doing click on image i have added tapGesture then it open gallery then selected image that upload in Firebase and also i add textField Value Too i hope it helps you Thank  You

```
import UIKit
import Firebase
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet var myImageView: UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet var txtText: UITextField!
    var ref = DatabaseReference.init()
    var imagePicker = UIImagePickerController()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.ref = Database.database().reference()
        let tapGestureRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(ViewController.openGalleryClick(tapGesture:)))
        myImageView.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
        myImageView.addGestureRecognizer(tapGestureRecognizer)
        myImageView.backgroundColor = UIColor.red
    }

    @objc func openGalleryClick(tapGesture: UITapGestureRecognizer){
        self.setupImagePicker()
    }

    @IBAction func btnSaveClick(_ sender: UIButton) {
         self.saveFIRData()
    }

    func saveFIRData(){
        self.uploadMedia(image: myImageView.image!){ url in
            self.saveImage(userName: self.txtText.text!, profileImageURL: url!){ success in
                if (success != nil){
                    self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
                }

            }
        }
    }


    func uploadMedia(image :UIImage, completion: @escaping ((_ url: URL?) -> ())) {
        let storageRef = Storage.storage().reference().child("myimage.png")
        let imgData = self.myImageView.image?.pngData()
        let metaData = StorageMetadata()
        metaData.contentType = "image/png"
        storageRef.putData(imgData!, metadata: metaData) { (metadata, error) in
            if error == nil{
                storageRef.downloadURL(completion: { (url, error) in
                    completion(url)
                })
            }else{
                print("error in save image")
                completion(nil)
            }
        }
    }

    func saveImage(userName:String, profileImageURL: URL , completion: @escaping ((_ url: URL?) -> ())){
        let dict = ["name": "Yogesh", "text": txtText.text!, "profileImageURL": profileImageURL.absoluteString] as [String : Any]
        self.ref.child("chat").childByAutoId().setValue(dict)
    }

}


extension ViewController: UINavigationControllerDelegate, UIImagePickerControllerDelegate{

    func setupImagePicker(){
        if UIImagePickerController.isSourceTypeAvailable(.savedPhotosAlbum){
            imagePicker.sourceType = .savedPhotosAlbum
            imagePicker.delegate = self
            imagePicker.allowsEditing = true

            self.present(imagePicker, animated: true, completion: nil)
        }
    }

    func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [UIImagePickerController.InfoKey : Any]) {

        let image = info[UIImagePickerController.InfoKey.originalImage] as! UIImage
        myImageView.image = image
        picker.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    }


}
```