# Store Facebook Profile Photo in Firebase Storage

Tags: xcode, facebook, firebase, swift3, firebase-storage

I am trying to implement facebook login into my application.

So far I have been able to authenticate the facebook user, meaning it shows up in the authentication tab.

I just finished storing the user information into the database, including the profile image URL.

Now all that is left to do is for me to store the profile image into the Firebase Storage. I'm not sure how to do this,

PLEASE HELP!!

This is my code for storing the user and image URL into the database

```
  graphRequest.start(completionHandler: { (connection, result, error) in

                        if let userDetails = result as? [String: String] {

                        if error != nil {

                            print(error!)
                            return

                        } else {


                            let id = userDetails["id"]
                            let profileImageURL = "http://graph.facebook.com/\(id!)/picture?type=large"
                            let email = userDetails["email"]
                            let name = userDetails["name"]

                            self.setUserInformation(profileImageUrl: profileImageURL, username: name!, email: email!, uid: uid)



                        }
                        }

                    })
```

Comment: follow this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37780672/uploading-images-from-uiimage-picker-onto-new-firebase-swift

Comment: Why do you want to store this in Firebase Storage when you can rely on the Facebook graph URL to get a profile picture?